boxed proof compile error when there is no word in the theorem
I have a trivial theorem that is like:
\begin{Prop}
\[1+1=2\]
\begin{proof}
Trivial.
\end{proof}
\end{Prop}

and my overleaf marks the "Trivial" red and says:
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Everything works as intended, but the red mark just won't go.
Then, I tried adding some comment to the proposition
\begin{Prop}
This statement is true:
\[1+1=2\]
\begin{proof}
Trivial.
\end{proof}
\end{Prop}

and the red mark is gone.
Why is this?
This is the code to duplicate the problem:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newmdtheoremenv{Prop}{Proposition}

\surroundwithmdframed{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{Prop}
    \[1+1=2\]
    \begin{proof}
        Trivial.
    \end{proof}
\end{Prop}

\end{document}

The result:

The error:

Also, if I remove the \usepackage{amsmath}, the line would be fine. This is also strange.

well I wished chatgpt would also mention that one always need a complete example to text code, not only some snippet from the header. Generally: use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. Much more modern and stable.

remove all the code unrelated to the question, but make a small complete example that generates the error message that you are asking about.

thanks for deleting the unnecessary code, but we still don't have code we can use to reproduce the problem. We should be able to copy-paste-compile your code to reproduce the problem you want help with.

As Ulrike told in a comment, I would recommend to use tcolorbox instead of mdframed:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtheorem{Prop}{Proposition}
\tcolorboxenvironment{Prop}{colback=white}
\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{colback=white}
\begin{document}

\begin{Prop}
    \[1+1=2\]
    \begin{proof}
        Trivial.
    \end{proof}
\end{Prop}

\end{document}


Instead of first defining the new theorem environment using \newtheorem and afterwards converting it into a tcolorbox environment using \tcolorboxenvironment, you can alternatively directly define a boxed theorem environment using \NewTcbTheorem. Please, see the tcolorbox manual for more information.
